# Proof that a bipartite graph cannt exist with this degree sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there a bipartite graph with degree sequence $3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,9$?
 Answer is No.Here's my justification:

Suppose there exists such a bipartite graph G with the given degree sequence.And let the two partitions be $U,V$.
WLOG suppose the vertex with degree 9 is in $V$.Then $U$ should have at least 9 vertices.
In order to have a vertex with degree 6, it should definitely be in $V$.After creating two vertices with degree 6 in order to have another vertex with degree 6, we should have at least one vertex in $V$.But then we would be having a least 13 vertices in G.This is a contradiction as the given degree sequence has only 12 vertices.
Therefore such a bipartite graph cannot exist.

I would like to know if this is a correct proof or if something is wrong with it as I ma finding it really difficult to prove graph theory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you have said is incorrect, but maybe a little more involved than is necessary. Call the degree-9 vertex $v$. There are at least nine vertices opposite $v$. So there are at most 3 vertices on the side that $v$ is on. So there must be at least one (actually at least four) degree-6 vertex on the side opposite $v$. But this means there are at least 6 vertices on the same side $v$. "at most 3" contradicts "at least 6".

Comment: The degrees add up to $60$, so there are $30$ edges; if the graph is bipartite, the degrees on each side must add up to $30$. But there is a vertex of degree $9$, so there are at least $9$ vertices on one side, at most $3$ on the other. But this is impossible, because the three highest degrees add up to only $9+6+6=21$.